EF Core trying to access wrong Database that was never added to project
I'm having quite the weird error. I'm performing some actions in my controller, and when I trigger one of them using AJAX, I get the following error:
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update[10000]
      An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'App_Escaner.Data.DatabaseContext'.
      Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
       ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Saadis_Internet..COMPROB'.

It seems it is trying to reference Saadis_internet, but I NEVER added a reference to that database, only to Saadis. There are multiple tables that are in both Saadis and Saadis_internet.
I tried running an SQL query directly with the connection string to check if it worked, and it did, like so:
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 10 * FROM COMPROB", connection);
    var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(reader[0].ToString());
    }
}

I tried: deleting and reinstalling nuget packages, checking the connection string, removing migrations, cleaning and rebuilding the project (after each of the previous steps), deleting SQL database cache, and nothing worked.
I tried duplicating the project, and in the duplicated one, overriding all the models and context using the scaffold command with the connection string (the same that I tested directly before)
And nothing worked, I still get that error. The database Saadis_internet is not even anymore on my SQL Server instance, I only have the Saadis database.
Here is the code of the action I'm testing:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCbtFromHr(string cbt, string hr)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cbt)) return BadRequest("Comprobante no valido.");

    var fCbt = new GetFormattedCbt().FormatCbt(cbt);

    try
    {
        var comp = await context.Comprobs
        .Where(x =>
            x.CbtNrocbt == fCbt["nroCbt"] &&
            x.CbtCenemi == fCbt["centEmi"] &&
            x.CbtLetcbt == fCbt["letra"] &&
            x.CbtNrohru == hr
        )
        .FirstOrDefaultAsync();

        if (comp == null) return BadRequest("El comprobante no existe.");
        // Actualizar nrohru, fleter, fleuni y estado del cbt
        comp.CbtEstado = "1";
        comp.CbtNrohru = "";
        comp.CbtFleter = "";
        comp.CbtFleuni = "";
        // Buscar registro de cbt en COSTCBT
        var costcbt = await context.Costcbt
            .Where(x =>
                x.Cliente == comp.CbtNrocli &&
                x.CbtCodcbt == comp.CbtCodcbt &&
                x.CbtCenemi == comp.CbtCenemi &&
                x.CbtNrocbt == comp.CbtNrocbt &&
                x.CbtLetcbt == comp.CbtLetcbt)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        // actualizar importe, impcrr, kilos_afo, bultos, val_decla, hranulada, enviado, plrema
        if (costcbt != null)
        {
            costcbt.Importe = 0;
            costcbt.CosImpcrr = 0;
            costcbt.KilosAfo = 0;
            costcbt.Bultos = 0;
            costcbt.ValDecla = 0;
            costcbt.Hranulada = "A";
            costcbt.Plrema = 0;
        }
        // guardar cambios
        await context.SaveChangesAsync(); --> HERE IS WHERE THE ERROR TRIGGERS
        // Ejecutar store para generar etapa
        await context.Database.ExecuteSqlRawAsync("EXEC [dbo].[spBorrarComprobHR] @CBT_CENEMI, @CBT_NROCBT, @CBT_LETCBT, @CBT_NROCLI, @CBT_CODCBT, @CBT_NROHRU, @OP",
            new SqlParameter("@CBT_CENEMI", comp.CbtCenemi),
            new SqlParameter("@CBT_NROCBT", comp.CbtNrocbt),
            new SqlParameter("@CBT_LETCBT", comp.CbtLetcbt),
            new SqlParameter("@CBT_NROCLI", comp.CbtNrocli),
            new SqlParameter("@CBT_CODCBT", comp.CbtCodcbt),
            new SqlParameter("@CBT_NROHRU", comp.CbtNrohru),
            new SqlParameter("@OP", HttpContext.Session.GetString("Operador"))
        );
        // devolver vista
        return PartialView("_CbtDeleteResult");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
}

And this is the connection string:
"default": "Server=localhost\\SQLDEV; Database=Saadis; Integrated Security=False;user=*;pwd=*; TrustServerCertificate=True;"
As I mentioned before, there is not a single line of code referencing to Saadis_internet anywhere in the project. If needed I can copy the context code but it is quite large.
Thank you.

Unfortunately we lost all the comments from the staging area... but you can reference them vis the history icon on the side - cos you are going to need to provide the requested information.

Check the connection string at runtime using context.Database.GetConnectionString() and verify it is going to the expected database. If it is using "Saadis_internet" then you have an outdated .exe.config or .web.config with a connection string reference that is out of date. Sometimes these get out of sync with the development environment.

Did you actually do a 'Find in Files' for "Saadis_Internet"?

Is there a chance you have a view or stored procedure in your "Saadis" instance that references your "Saadis_internet" instance?

Maybe this stored procedure [dbo].[spBorrarComprobHR]?

The error was pretty simple and dumb: there were soome triggers pointing to that other database and I did not know they were there, until I started checking table by table. I disabled them all and it worked, so always check those kind of things.
